# Why is part of Tenjin's hat transparent?

Tags: noragami

Everything else is solid except for the sliver that is hanging off the back. Why is this transparent?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The headgear is called a Kanmuri and that translucent part is just a thin layer of cloth/mesh attached to the headgear.

[image]

http://philippi-collection.blogspot.com/2011/02/headgear-of-japanese-shinto-priests.html

Comment: According to (http://www.kariginu.jp/kikata/2-2.htm), the semi-transparent part is specifically called an _ei_ (纓).

Comment: @senshin Kanmuri is the headgear. I updated my answer so it would be less confusing which is which